# Find largest positive real root of polynomial

Tags: list-manipulation

First let me tell you that I am absolutely new to Mathematica.

I would like to find the largest positive real root of the polynomial

$$
x^4-x ³-1
$$
and to save it.

To this end, I did the following:

```
f[x] := x^4 - x^3 -1;
realroots = NSolve[f[x],x,Reals];
realmax = Max[realroots];
```

The variable realroots then equals

```
{{x -> -0.819173}, {x -> 1.38028}}
```

Unfortunately the variable realmax does not equal the largest value; instead I just get the output

```
Max[x -> -0.819173, x -> 1.38028]
```

How can I pick the larger one?

Comment: Solutions of `Solve`, `NSolve` and many other solving routines are returned as list of rules (look up `->` also known as `Rule` in the documentation). All you have to do is to `Replace` `x` by the rules in `realroot`: `Max[x /. realroots]` (`/.` is a shorthand for `ReplaceAll`).

Comment: The definition of `f` should be `f[x_] := x^4 - x^3 -1`, i.e., use a pattern on the LHS so that the function can be used with arguments other than the symbol `x`

Answer (score 2):

What this finds:

```
roots = NSolve[x^4 - x^3 - 1, x, Reals]
```

> `{{x -> -0.819173}, {x -> 1.38028}}`

This gives you the actual `x` values:

```
x /. roots
```

> `{-0.819173, 1.38028}`

And what you are looking for is

```
Max[x /. roots]
```

> `1.38028`

Comment: Also `Max@Values@NSolve[x^4 - x^3 - 1 == 0, x, Reals]` and `NMaxValue[{x, x^4 - x^3 - 1 == 0}, x]`.